# How to pass the first argument to lapply so that it represents a list of "rows" of the dataframe

Tags: r

A functionn called "myfun1" takes as an argument a single row in "my_df". The functionn calculates and returns the values for two columns (There are 12 columns) How to use lapply to call "myfun1" for all rows of my_df? The first argument to "lapply" should represents a list of "rows

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: I agree that having a simple reproducible example would have been helpful. It was just that the original code was complicated with requirements for MCSIM and so on.

Answer (score 0):

If the function is taking numeric values as input or single class elements, then `apply` would be an option

```
 t(apply(df1, 1, myfun1))
```

---

`lapply/sapply/vapply` etc loop thorough the columns and not by rows.  So, if we need to use `lapply`, then loop through the sequence of rows, and then the unit will be a single element of that sequence (with `data.frame`, each unit is a column)

```
lapply(seq_len(nrow(df1)), function(i) myfun1(df1[i,]))
```

Comment: lapply(seq_len(nrow(df1)), function(i) myfun1(df1[i,])) did work.

Answer (score 0):

Will the following solve your problem:

```
lapply(1:nrow(my_df),function(i){
myfun1(my_df[i,])
}
)
```

Let me know if that works. Thanks.

Comment: Yes. That did work. once the missing closing brace } was added as

Comment: lapply(1:nrow(my_df),function(i){
  myfun1(my_df[i,])
})